# How to create a special binary tree

Tags: c#, indexing, binary-tree

I wish to index some data where the key is a ulong.
This ulong (64 bits) represents a combo of products,
where each bit of the ulong is a Product in the combo.

So if we get a ulong Key of value 3. That's really 1 + 2.
That means that products 1 and 2 are present in the combo.

```
ulong Combo1 = 1 | 2;
ulong Combo2 = 1 | 4 | 8;
```

If I wish to know if Combo1 shares any product with Combo2 I could simply do this:

```
if((Combo1 & Combo2) != 0)
{
  //They share at least 1 product
}
```

This is very nice and fast, but it gets difficult if I have:

```
List<ulong> Combos = new List<ulong>();
```

And in it over 1 million Combo Keys (the key represents the products used).

How can I index this list of ulongs so that I can loop it and do the following:

```
foreach(ulong combo in Combos)
{
  //Find all the combos in Combos where no product is shaded
  List<ulong> WorksWith = GetFromIndexOrTree(combo);
  foreach(ulong combo2 in WorksWith)
  {
    //Use
  }
}

private List<ulong> GetFromIndexOrTree(ulong combo)
{
  //magic index or tree
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help and for the comments.

Say I am a combo with products (red, blue, and white). I wish to find all combos that don't have any or all of my products (red, blue and white). So I shall find a combo with (yellow), (green, yellow), (green, black)...

[image: Works - Don't works]

Comment: So you have 64 products and each product is used in one or more combo, and you want the minimal set of combos such that no combo overlaps with any other in the set and the set covers all products?

Comment: Do you want ulong's from the same set that do __not__ share a bit?

Comment: Hi Mike,

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly. What exactly do you mean by "no product is shaded"?

Comment: dtb: 64 products distribute in combos. The goal is to find rapidly the combos that don't match (have no products in common), nothing else. Henk: Totally right. Find the combos that don't have the products I have. Madsen: Say I am a combo. I wish to find all combos that don't have any or all of my products.

Comment: You example is a bit unclear - in the last sentence you say you want to find combos wich don't have any or all of (red, blue and white) and then one product you want to find is (green, black, white) - so why does this one qualify despite containing white ?

Comment: Yahia you are totally right. Fixed, Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Let

*S*   be the set of products.

*C* ⊂ [*P*(S)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)   the set of combos.

*F(p)* = { *c* ∈ *C* | *p* ∉ *c* }   the set of all combos *c* ∈ C that do not contain the product *p* ∈ S.

Then

*G(X)* = ∩<sub>*p*∈*X*</sub> *F(p)*

gives the set of combos  where no combo contains any product *p* in the set of products *X* ⊂ *S*.

---

*C#*

```
List<ulong> combos = new List<ulong> { 1 | 2, 1 | 4 | 8 };

Dictionary<int, List<ulong>> dict = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 64)
    .ToDictionary(i => i, i => combos
        .Where(combo => ((1UL << i) & combo) == 0)
        .ToList());

ulong input = 1 | 2; // find all combos that don't have product 1 or 2

List<ulong> result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 64)
    .Where(i => ((1UL << i) & input) != 0)
    .Select(i => dict[i])
    .Aggregate((a, b) => Enumerable
        .Intersect(a, b)
        .ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And if I wish to index a class named Combo where the ulong is a Key attribute how would I use this code? I will test it out to make millions of queries. Thanks

Comment: The example finds all combos that don't have product 1 or 2. All combos in the example have product 1. So the result is empty.